# T-SQL WHERE for specific value

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

How to modify this script to only the select the latest execution for each job name?

```
SELECT 
    j.name JobName,
    h.step_name StepName, 
    CONVERT(CHAR(10), CAST(STR(h.run_date,8, 0) AS dateTIME), 111) RunDate, 
    STUFF(STUFF(RIGHT('000000' + CAST ( h.run_time AS VARCHAR(6)), 6), 5, 0, ':'), 3, 0, ':') RunTime, 
    h.run_duration StepDuration,
    case h.run_status 
       when 0 then 'failed'
       when 1 then 'Succeded' 
       when 2 then 'Retry' 
       when 3 then 'Cancelled' 
       when 4 then 'In Progress' 
    end as ExecutionStatus, 
    h.message MessageGenerated
FROM 
    sysjobhistory h 
INNER JOIN 
    sysjobs j ON j.job_id = h.job_id
ORDER BY 
    j.name, h.run_date DESC
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

Change order by as per your need..

```
SELECT j.name JobName,h.step_name StepName, 
CONVERT(CHAR(10), CAST(STR(h.run_date,8, 0) AS dateTIME), 111) RunDate, 
STUFF(STUFF(RIGHT('000000' + CAST ( h.run_time AS VARCHAR(6 ) ) ,6),5,0,':'),3,0,':') RunTime, 
h.run_duration StepDuration,
case h.run_status when 0 then 'failed'
when 1 then 'Succeded' 
when 2 then 'Retry' 
when 3 then 'Cancelled' 
when 4 then 'In Progress' 
end as ExecutionStatus, 
h.message MessageGenerated
 sysjobs j
 cross apply
 (
 select top 1 b.columns you need 
 from sys.jobhistory b where b.job_id=j.job_id
 order by RunDate desc
 ) h
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on not working,you have to choose columns from job history